# Indexing does not stop in Laravel 8 project using Laravel Sail in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, laravel-8, docker-desktop, laravel-sail

I am working on a project created in Laravel 8 Sail and running on Docker Desktop (Windows 10 Pro). The problem is that PhpStorm keeps indexing continuously...

[image]

[image]

I searched the internet for the solution the only thing I found is
[image]

```
File -> Invalidate Caches
```

but that doesn't work either!
Do you have a solution?

Comment: Do you have any WSL involved here in this project (I mean: where the project files are located)? If it's WSL, have a look at workarounds at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-286059 . If that is not your case -- better contact JetBrains Support Team with such requests as this requires looking into your logs. You can do this from "PhpStorm | Help | Contact Support..." where you can privately provide all requested info

Comment: Yes I use, 
ubuntu 20.04 LTS and WSL 2

Comment: Thx @LazyOne for ur tips. I think the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. press Shift-Shift to open "Search everywhere"
2. Enter "Experimental features" and select the action
3. In the dialog that appears, turn off wsl.fsd.content.loader
4. save
5. Restart PHPStorm

Comment: The issue ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-286059 is marked as Fixed so it should appear in the next minor update (2021.3.2 I would assume). Once you get that new version (when it will become available) -- revert the changes you have made for `wsl.fsd.content.loader` and check how it works after restarting the IDE.